# Publish simple project to AWS Beanstalk

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, signalr, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to upload a very simple .NET MVC C# project into AWS, to EU Central (Frankfurt).

This simple project uses SignalR and is a chat that I picked up from a tutorial, and is attached to this post.
https://copy.com/OYMrnXbXDPJMSWmA

I have been trying to publish this project on AWS Beanstalk, but so far I have had no success at all. I have uploaded the zip file to the link:
https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home?region=eu-central-1#/environment/dashboard?applicationName=My%20First%20Elastic%20Beanstalk%20Application&environmentId=e-r6quc7xrfv

But it gives me an error I cannot understand.

I also installed VisualStudio dev tools, but I can't publish via there either because no matter what I do, I always get an URL error (and I have the account with the correct keys configured!)

What is the proper way of deploying this project? What am I missing?

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually showed the error. "Error I cannot understand" is not something that can be acted on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this application were the user permissions. Even though I had the correct access key and secret keys, the problem is that the user was inside a group that did not had explicit access to the BeanStalk service.

Finding this was no trivial task, because the error that I had was as vague as an error could be.

I hope that this helps someone in the future.